# convert date 08-03-2016 to 08-Mar-2016 format

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datetime

from spreadsheet i am taking date in "dd-MM-yyyy"(08-03-2016) format

```
datetime date = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Date"]);
```

how to convert it in dd-MMM-yyyy(08-Mar-2016) format?

Comment: You have just done it... the format is exactly in your question, use `DateTime` `struct` to do that in C# (downvote is not mine)

Comment: You have a string "08-03-2016" and you want to convert it to an other string "08-Mar-2016", isn't that ?

Comment: I don't understand why they downvoted you? you're right to ask help

Comment: Thanks guys these both answers is working fine. Sorry i am not able to vote you cause of less points.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you:

```
string date = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Date"]).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# here is some code to convert a date:

```
static void Main()
{
    String date = DateTime.Parse("08-03-2016").ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Console.WriteLine(date);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```